# Let $f$ be a differentiable function with $f ′(x) = 4$. If $f(0) = 2$, find $f(3)$.

Tags: integration

So obviously this is some anti derivative stuff, and I the anti derivative would've been $2x^2$, with $f(x)=4x$ and then just plug in $x=3$ to get the answer. That's not the case tough, because with $f(x)=4x$, I see now that $f(0)$ does not equal $2$.

Comment: You are missing the constant. The antiderivative is $f(x)=4x+c$

Comment: Note that $f'(x)$ in the title is different from $f'(x)$ in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $ f(x) = \int f'(x)dx + C = 4x + C$, we have that $f(0) = C = 2$, hence $f(x) = 4x + 2$.

Hence, $f(3) = 12 + 2 = 14.$

Comment: ohhh that makes so mcuh sense!!! f(0) is basically telling us the constant is 2!!!! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that the differential of a constant function $f(x)=c$ is zero. That is to say, $$(f(x)+c)'\equiv f'(x)$$

To account for this, you must add $c$ whenever you integrate without limits.